# GridCacheSwapEntry unmarshalling exception

Tags: gridgain

I'm setting-up a GridGain in-memory file system, but when I access a file on it I'm getting this exception.

It looks like that the cause is a GridCacheSwapEntry unmarshalling exception, but I have no clue why it is raised and how it could solved.

Any idea what is the reason of this exception?

```
Apr-30 23:19:22.782 [gridgain-#11%pub-nextflow%] ERROR o.g.g.util.future.GridFutureAdapter - Failed to execute compound future reducer: Compound future listener: GridCompoundFuture [lsnrCalls=0, finished=false, rdc=null, init=true, res=java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicMarkableReference@ee9890e, err=null, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[true]]
org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheTxRollbackException: Transaction has been rolled back: 4965184b541-009e468e-0000-0001-0000-0145b481969b
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.syncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:3596) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.removeAll(GridCacheAdapter.java:2587) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.dataload.GridDataLoadCacheUpdaters.updateAll(GridDataLoadCacheUpdaters.java:99) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.dataload.GridDataLoadCacheUpdaters$BatchedSorted.update(GridDataLoadCacheUpdaters.java:211) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.dataload.GridDataLoadUpdateJob.call(GridDataLoadUpdateJob.java:85) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.wrapThreadLoader(GridUtils.java:6088) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:773) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:137) [gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@28404eb2
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal(GridOptimizedMarshaller.java:352) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheSwapManager.unmarshal(GridCacheSwapManager.java:1364) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheSwapManager.swapEntry(GridCacheSwapManager.java:370) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheSwapManager.readAndRemove(GridCacheSwapManager.java:467) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheSwapManager.readAndRemove(GridCacheSwapManager.java:573) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.unswap(GridCacheMapEntry.java:463) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.enlistWrite(GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.java:1798) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.removeAllAsync0(GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.java:2419) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.removeAllAsync(GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.java:2356) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.removeAll(GridCacheTxLocalAdapter.java:1654) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$43.inOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:2589) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$SyncInOp.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:4669) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.syncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:3583) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected error occurred during unmarshalling of an instance of the class: org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheSwapEntry. Check that all nodes are running the same version of GridGain and that all nodes have GridOptimizedMarshaller configured with identical optimized classes lists, if any (see setClassNames and setClassNamesPath methods). If your serialized classes implement java.io.Externalizable interface, verify that serialization logic is correct.
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(GridOptimizedObjectInputStream.java:143) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal(GridOptimizedMarshaller.java:349) ~[gridgain-platform-6.1.0.jar:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does this exception easily reproducible? Can you provide client-side code reproducing this issue? Also, are you using swap or off-heap? If you want to use off-heap, I would recommend to use store off-heap values only (see GridCacheMemoryMode#OFFHEAP_VALUES). Generally, swap should not be used with GGFS since it can be configured to use HDFS as backing file system.

Comment: You can find the the client-side exception here http://pastebin.com/HbnwZcLg 

Anyway I'm using off-heap only for values (ggfs-data) cache configuration. It turns out that the exception is raised if I set memoryMode = GridCacheMemoryMode.OFFHEAP_TIERED, otherwise it works fine. Is this configuration supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulecci,

This exception is caused by a well-known HotSpot bug affecting JDK7, which will be resolved in the upcoming JDK7 update (release date is not known at the moment).

We implemented workaround for this problem which will be avaialble in the nearest GridGain release 6.1.5 (will be available in the nearest 1-2 weeks).

Comment: OK, thanks for replying. Is it also the JDK8 affected by this bug?

Comment: @Paulecci I don't think that JDK8 is affected by this bug.

Comment: @Paulecci, no JDK8 is not affected, so you can also switch to JDK8 as a workaround.